# How to open laravel application by a browser on another network (using public ip)

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I have laravel application in my server. I can access the server by remote desktop. And when im in the server, I used the "php artisan serve" and it worked. It will open the home view when we hit "localhost:8000". But here is the question:



How can I open the laravel application served by the server from my computer's browser? 
(I mean without remote desktop, just open it with my browser. My server and my computer is not physically connected, they're connected by the internet which mean I must use the server's public ip to access the application)

let's say the public ip of the serve is : 123.123.123.123



I do this to test my application. If you think you can help please don't hesitate post it. Thank you

I already tried "php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000" on the server and visit "ip address:port" from another device but it didn't work.

And I got this message:

```
This site can’t be reached

refused to connect
Search Google for
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Are you using a mac or a windows machine? In mac, you could use [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/valet) to share it over a temporary domain.

Comment: @Sajal windows machine

Answer (score 3):

First start your server as "php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000"

Then run this url "123.123.123.123:8000" from your another device

Comment: **note** Be sure you have forwarded the correct ports on your router as well

Comment: **note2** And make sure port 8000 is whitelistes for at least TCP in your firewall. And if you mapped port 8000 internal to another port external visit the mapped port trough your browser

Comment: I already tried "php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000" on the server and visit "ip address:port" from another device but it didn't work. Any suggestion why it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

[Hamachi](https://www.vpn.net/)  easy and safe way but free version have 5 member limit